# What Is The Best Practice To Validate a Property of a Controller In an In another Controller Validation

Tags: event-observer, validation, best-practice

Let me explain a demo situation.

I need to allow only logged in customers to subscribe newsletter. So in newsletter controller, I am validating whether the user is guest or a valid customer. If the user is guest, I am redirecting the user to log-in page.

Now suppose user is logging into his account. In that case, during the success login, I need to automatically make newsletter subscription for that user. In order to do this operation, I need to get subscription details during the validation action takes place.

*What is the best way to do this ?*

These are my ideas.

1) Make a global object that holds newsletter details (using `Mage::register()`)

2) Create a session that holds newsletter for future validation.

3) send newsletter details via url to login page and then use those data there

**Note:** I will most probably use an observer for validation. So I need to varify newsletter status over there :)

Thanks in advance for any kind of suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this by `preDispatch` function of controllers. Magento triggers `preDispatch`  function before any controller action get dispatched.

So You need to add a new `preDispatch()` on your controller and  **check whether customer is logged in or not**. ***If logged in***,then routers will go to ***Newsletter Save Action*** and If customer is ***not logged in***, then router will redirect to  ***Customer Log-in Action***, after setting your  *request save action to session variable*. This is how it saves to the session.

```
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getBeforeUrl();
```

### Description with an Example

## step 1

Create a helper function that will allow us to save the subscription-save-url along with current url that is encoded.` That is,

```
 public function getSaveUrl()
 {
     return $this->_getUrl(
              'yourmodule/yourcotroller/yoursaveaction', 
              array(
                  'myflagnewsletter'    => true,
                   Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED => $this->getEncodedUrl()
     ));
 }
```

## step 2

After click on the link, you will redirect to your own controller and there, you will check whether customer is logged in or not with the help of `predisPatch` function. Using this function, we will prevent redirection to the matching action (means  subscriber save action)

```
   public function preDispatch()
   {
        parent::preDispatch();

        if (!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->authenticate($this)) {
            $this->setFlag('', 'no-dispatch', true);
            if(!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getBeforeUrl()) {
                Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setBeforeUrl($this->_getRefererUrl());
            }
        }
   }
```

If Customer is not logged-in, then the request url get saved to `BeforeUrl` property by default. This will then use to redirect the customer to  subscriber-save-action after customer-login-action took place.

## Step 3

After successfully logged-in, now Magento will redirect to subscriber controller and again  checks `predispatch` function ,`customer is logged or not .As now customer is logged in, it will fail condition inside the function and thus continue to the subscriber-save-action method. This should somewhat looks like this.

```
    public function yoursaveactionAction()
    {
        $session = Mage::getSingleton('core/session');

       $backUrl    = $this->getRequest()->getParam(Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED);
        $customerflag  = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('myflagnewsletter');

        if (!$backUrl || !$customerflag  ) {
            $this->_redirect('/');
            return ;
        }

        if ($backUrl && !$customerflag) {
            $session->addError($this->__('Not enough parameters.'));
            $this->_redirectUrl($backUrl);
            return ;
        }

        try {

            // save you model
            $session->addSuccess($this->__('Alert subscription has been saved.'));
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            $session->addException($e, $this->__('Unable to update the alert subscription.'));
        }
        $this->_redirectReferer();
    }
```

Comment: you provided a good solution though but why are you using so many code ticks "`" they are used for highlighting the code only, you should format the answer bit nicely.

Comment: just give example... how it executed

Comment: hey tomy,is it works?

Comment: I got your point. as @MTM said you are using two much of "string enhancing" which makes it difficult to get at first time. I have edited your code. Hope that will not bother you. Now it looks clean for every one. Now your first part (not example) is a good point. I will try it in my module and will let you know

Comment: preDispatch function uses the session to return back to the original controller. If the customer takes more time to register/login and session expires, he won't be subscribed and has to go again with the process.

Answer (score 0):

If you use sessions or `Mage::register`, then guests will not be able to subscribe after a certain time period. depends on session expiration limit. while if you want the customers to get subscribed whenever they login using the link you provide, then you can use the third option where you can append a variable like `subscribe=1` and access it in the observer.

Comment: ya I can do this ofcourse. However still it doesn't answer my question fully. I want to do the above thing, when the user try to subscribe the newsletter only. But this code will automatically make subscription every time customer logs in. More clearly, I need to do the above code if the user tried to subscribe newsletter. To make that condition, I need to do something in newsletter controller and then check that status later in login action. Did you get me now ?

Comment: updated the answer

Comment: yes. But there is another problem for the third option. if I append that value, then redirection url look like `www.mydomain.com/customer/account/login/subscribe=1`. But when user logins, means when he press submit button, the url processing would be another one example `www.mydomain.com/customer/account/validte/<credentials>`. Due to this I cant validate it that simply in observer. Its my guess. Whats your thought ?

Comment: In that case I think you can use a combination of 2nd and third option, on account create/login page you should set a session which holds the value of subscribe. which you can easily access in observer.